# Programmatically firing a click handler

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I'm using dojo. I've got something like this:

```
<a id="fooBar" onclick="foo();bar();">Foo then Bar</a>
```

I want to trigger `fooBar`'s click handler from another button. Something like:

```
<a onclick="dojo.query('#fooBar')[0].click()">Do FooBar</a>
```

Can I do that?

Comment: `Cam O do that?` Why don't you try?

Comment: because, as I expected, `dojo.query("<path to node>")[0].click is not a function`

Comment: `eval(document.getElementById('fooBar').getAttribute('onclick'));` would work yes? Though I feel dirty for even thinking it...

Comment: yeah, I thought of that. don't really like it either. and I'm not sure it would work in my case, because in reality, it's more like foo(event).

Comment: Do you have control over the markup? Shoving a string inside an `onclick` attribute is just as much `eval` as calling it directly. Event attributes should not really be used at all, and even less so when they contain statements instead of just function references.

Comment: It's shouldn't be `foo(event)` but more like `<element>.onclick = function(event) { foo();bar(); }`

Comment: Just remember that you **cannot** synthesize a real event in some browsers such as FF -- even if you *can* invoke a previously defined event callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dojo.byId('fooBar').onclick();
```

or

```
dojo.query('#fooBar')[0].onclick();
```

[See examples](http://jsfiddle.net/Djgvw/).

I haven't used Dojo before, but can safely say that you can do better than inline events :). Moreover, these will not be managed by Dojo as they were added inline. The `onclick` method here is a native DOM method for triggering the function attached to the `onclick` property of the element.

`dojo.byId` is a shortcut to `document.getElementById`, and honestly you can easily do without Dojo here:

```
document.getElementById("fooBar").onclick();
```

Here's the [three methods](http://jsfiddle.net/Djgvw/1/) with a comparison of character savings (9 and 14):

```
document.getElementById('fooBar').onclick();
dojo.query('#fooBar')[0].onclick();123456789
dojo.byId('fooBar').onclick();12345678901234
```

---

See a couple of good reasons for [not using inline click handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848812/why-its-recommended-not-use-onclicks-in-your-html-use-event-handlers-in-your-js-f/2848831#2848831).

Comment: well stated, though dojo.byId does a tad bit of work working around form/id/name mishaps, so isn't quite a straight alias. There is a function in a mini project of mine to trigger native and custom dom events (dojo.trigger('foobar', "click")) but even that is more expensive than just calling the click function. ideally, one would bind a named/namespaced click function to a node via attachEvent/addEventListener (dojo.connect), and simply call that function directly rather than touching the dom at all. In Dojo we have dojo.publish and dojo.subscribe for a pattern based on that concept.